# How to show all windows like in the Windows tab of Windows Task Manager?

Tags: 14.04, windows, task-management

How to show all windows like in the Windows tab of Windows Task Manager?

Here is some extra text to bypass AskUbuntu's quality filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list and don't mind a terminal command, you can try this in terminal:

```
wmctrl -l
```

If you're looking for something graphical you can try installing window-list indicator:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/display-open-windows-on-panel/

Comment: Any non-terminal application that does not run 24/7?